# django custom tag inline or block

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I was wondering if there was a way to check if a tag has an endblock.  I am basically trying to let the user do

```
{% mytag 'a' 'b' 'c' %}
```

or

```
{% mytag 'a' 'b' 'c' %}
    <!-- other markup here -->
{% end mytag %}
```

I saw if that its not there it will raise an exception, but is there any way to programmatically setup my tag to safely  handle both situations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try parsing until the closing tag and catching the exception if it isn't found. You might want to stop if you run in to another mytag node also:

```
def do_mytag_stuff(parser, token):

    # Process your token however you need
    mytag_args = token.split_contents()

    try:
        nodelist = parser.parse(('endmytag', 'mytag'))
        token = parser.next_token()
        if token.contents == 'endmytag':
            # Found an ending tag, make a node for its contents
            parser.delete_first_token()
            return MyTagNode(nodelist, mytag_args)

    except TemplateSyntaxError:
        # Neither tag was found
        pass

    # So either there's no closing tag, or we met another mytag before a closing tag. 
    # Do whatever you would for a single tag here
    return SingleMyTagNode(mytag_args)
```

Not sure if that's 100% correct, but hopefully it will help.

Comment: I guess my only fear is that this might mask other issues.  Like people not typing something in correctly, including a template that DNE, etc.

Comment: Very true, I think just having two similar tags would be cleaner all round.

Comment: That might actually be a better solution, and they could share logic, so it would just be a facade.

Comment: I accepted but I think the better solution  would be to expose two tags *or* change the except to check for "expected endmytag or my tag."  It would prevent us from hiding compile exceptions un related to my tag.